# Retrieving elemnts from an ArrayList by specifying the indexes

Tags: java, arraylist, indexing

Is there a method in Java to get the list of objects from an Arraylist to another ArrayList, by just specifying the start and end index?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes you can use the [`subList` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList%28int,%20int%29):

```
List<...> list2 = list1.subList(startIndex, endIndex);
```

This returns a view on that part of the original list, it does not copy the data.
If you want a copy:

```
List<...> list2 = new ArrayList<...> (list1.subList(startIndex, endIndex));
```

Comment: That's right, but be aware that the references to the objects stay the same. So if you change your objects in the subList they will also be changed in the first list.

Comment: @Chris yes the second version is not a deep copy, it only copies objects' references.

Answer (score 0):

```
/create an ArrayList object
    ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();

    //Add elements to Arraylist
    arrayList.add("1");
    arrayList.add("2");
    arrayList.add("3");
    arrayList.add("4");
    arrayList.add("5");

    /*
       To get a sub list of Java ArrayList use
       List subList(int startIndex, int endIndex) method.
       This method returns an object of type List containing elements from
       startIndex to endIndex - 1.
    */

    List lst = arrayList.subList(1,3);

    //display elements of sub list.
    System.out.println("Sub list contains : ");
    for(int i=0; i< lst.size() ; i++)
      System.out.println(lst.get(i));
```