# Making A Copy of an Array List without it looping

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array which is uses inheritance i think basically there is an array which holds Food and Drink and looks something like this

```
allFoodAndDrink.add(new Food(parameters);
allFoodAndDrink.add(new Drink(parameters);
```

so both type food and drink are stored in the snack array called `allFoodAndDrink` but when wanting to make a copy of the array from certain start index to the a end index i got told to use:

```
Arrays.copyOfRange();
```

but when using it like this:

```
int[] drink = Arrays.copyOfRange(allFoodAndDrink, 5, 10);
```

it spits out and error and its suggestion is to convert it to `Arrays.copyOf()` when switching to that it then spits out another error to revert back to Previous

any ideas

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you looking to avoid by not looping? Some potential solutions may be worse, say, performance-wise.

Comment: Do you mean an `ArrayList` and not an Array? Because arrays don't have methods like `add()` on them.

Comment: Why are you assigning the copy to an int[], isn´t the type Food? Also allFoodAndDrink looks like a Collection of some sort, rather than a plain array?

Comment: Your `ArrayList` has `Food` and `Drink` objects in it. How is Java supposed to construct an `int` array from these? You should explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11880534/retrieving-elemnts-from-an-arraylist-by-specifying-the-indexes

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punctuation

Answer (score 2):

Make a use of [`ArrayList#subList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#subList%28int,%20int%29) and [`ArrayList#toArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray%28T%5b%5d%29):

```
int first = ...;
int last = ...;

Foods[] drink = new Foods[last - first];
allFoodAndDrink.subList(first, last).toArray(drink); // fill the array
```

Comment: Giving this an upvote because it's the best answer, but the issue still remains of converting `Food` and `Drink` objects to an `int` array, which doesn't actually work.

Comment: The issue of converting `Drink` to `Food` remains.  Without further knowledge from the asker, we can only assume their only similar superclass is `Object`, so for it to run, the array would need to be an `Object[]`.

Comment: @Vulcan I define the array as `Foods` assuming it's a super class of `Drink` and `Food`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean `ArrayList` and not array you can copy a `List` using

```
allFoodAndDrink.subList(5,10);
```

Please note that this would be a 'shallow copy' and references would point to the same objects

Comment: This doesn't address copying a *range* rather than the entire list.

Comment: @Eng Yes you're right... it might be preferable to use `new ArrayList(allFoodAndDrink.subList(5,10))` instead of adding a dependency

Comment: I  took out the use of Lists as it was superfluous

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ArrayList`'s method `sublist(int fromIndex, int toIndex)`.

```
ArrayList<Foods>() list = allFoodAndDrink.subList(0, allFoodAndDrink.size()-1);

Foods[] array = (Foods[]) list.toArray();
```

[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html#subList(int, int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html#subList%28int,%20int%29)

You can convert an `ArrayList` to an array with `toArray()`-method: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray()

Comment: This doesn't address copying a *range* rather than the entire list.

Comment: Although you've fixed the answer (and I thank you for that), it's now a near-exact duplicate of Eng.Fouad's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response I was just following and example that's where the int came from I'll try a few and get back to you